# J2ME implementation of a Trie (Ternary Search Tree )

Tags: java-me, trie, n-gram, ternary-search-tree

I am currently working on a predictive text SMS system. I want to implement it using TST data structure and bi-gram (Predicting the next probable word based on current key sequence 12-keypad).
Currently I have a corpus and have used the available applications to come up with a dictionary, bi-gram and frequencies. Currently have the following questions in mind:

1. Can I find a J2ME TST implementation or a suitable Trie on this case? (More detailed explanation on the available TST trie can be great)
2. A general guidance on this project approach

NB:I Have looked at similar Trie implementations but still unable to figure out a way forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may look at this: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/52trie/
Alternatives can be found at Algorithms, 4th Edition in general...